# Can admin mute a member in Facebook group using JavaSricpt SDK?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to mute members in my Facebook group using JavaScript SDK? There is a refererence on how to delete comment/post but not on how to mute or ban users in group. Is it impossible?
I want to make regex based app that monitors my group and deletes/mutes people who swear a lot.